# Open pull request but how pr commit applied?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

This is open pull request: https://github.com/CodeAndWeb/PhysicsEditor-Loaders/pull/14
As you see its not merged and still open.
But when I check corresponding files on origin master, PR changes applied to files

How PR commit applied to master files without merging PR?

Comment: The changes have not been applied to `master`. Taking https://github.com/CodeAndWeb/PhysicsEditor-Loaders/blob/master/generic-box2d-plist-cocos2d-x/GB2ShapeCache-x.cpp for example, the line `#include "CCNS.h"` has not been commented out yet.

Comment: its applied with same commit id 1e20318

Comment: https://github.com/gabjrb/PhysicsEditor-Loaders/tree/generic-box2d-plist-cocos2d-x-addShapesWithFile-for-v3  contributors branch is here 1e20318  id is same with origin : https://github.com/CodeAndWeb/PhysicsEditor-Loaders/blob/1e2031875f0d82adaec715b479b5a5f41d5b12e3/generic-box2d-plist-cocos2d-x/GB2ShapeCache-x.cpp

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you don't know how to read the PR? Let's take an example.

The second diff in that PR is in file *generic-box2d-plist-cocos2d-x/GB2ShapeCache-x.cpp*. It changes `CCPoint anchorPoint` to `Vec2 anchorPoint`. The first column is what currently exists; the second column is the suggested change:

[image]

If we actually look in that file, we still see `CCPoint anchorPoint`.

[image]

Or look at the last diff in the PR. It suggested changing *generic-box2d-plist-cocos2d-x/GB2ShapeCache-x.h* to remove the newline after `#endif` at line 60.

If we actually look in that file, there is still a newline after `#endif`.

[image]

So your premise is wrong. When we check the corresponding files on origin master, the PR changes have *not* been applied.

Comment: pr commit id hash and master file commit id hash is same: 1e20318 if its not applied why origin master file commit id is same with PR commit id? this is repo where hash id comes from: https://github.com/gabjrb/PhysicsEditor-Loaders/tree/generic-box2d-plist-cocos2d-x-addShapesWithFile-for-v3

Comment: @Tek Sure, but that's the commit in the pull _request_. That commit has never been merged into _master_ in the upstream. These are the commits on master: https://github.com/CodeAndWeb/PhysicsEditor-Loaders/commits/master And in any case, this commit would never appear on master even if it were merged in; what we would see would be the merge commit, which would have a different SHA.

Comment: thanks case solved its not merged.View file points to PR's file not master. thanks

Comment: Basically how a pull request works is: I make a branch in my fork and make the pull request, so that branch is copied lock-stock-and-barrel to the upstream (the repo we forked from). Now it is sitting there, still just a branch, until the owner decides to accept / merge it. But it looks like this owner has gone off to la-la-land.

Comment: See at the top of the pull request where it says "gabjrb wants to merge 1 commit into CodeAndWeb:master from gabjrb:generic-box2d-plist-cocos2d-x-addShapesWithFile-for-v3"? That means you are _not_ looking at `CodeAndWeb:master`; you are looking at a branch called `generic-box2d-plist-cocos2d-x-addShapesWithFile-for-v3` (on the fork repo).